# Selecting Table TD without TR

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html Table like this:

```
 <table>
   <tr onClick="someFunc();">
     <td>Foo</td>
     <td><button onClick="anotherFunc();">Bar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

and Javascript:

```
function somefunc(){
  alert("Foo");
}
function anotherfunc(){
  alert("Bar");
}
```

The problem is when I click on tr works fine but when I press on the button inside TD it fires both functions so I want when I click on the button to just fire the button function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, do not use inline handler with jQuery. That separates the handler from the registration for no good reason and leads to maintenance problems. Use classes or IDs to match the elements and use jQuery handlers.

The problem is event propagation. To stop the click propagating use `e.stopPropagation()` in the handler:

```
<table>
   <tr class="doSomeFunc">
     <td>Foo</td>
     <td><button class="doAnotherFunc">Bar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

$('.doSomeFunc').click(function(e){
  alert("Foo");
});

$('.doAnotherFunc').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert("Bar");
});
```

If you want to stick with your existing *non-jQuery* code, just change this:

```
<button onClick="anotherFunc();return false;">
```

`return false` from a mouse handler will do the same as `e.stopPropagation()` *and* `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: OP has tagged jQuery, but his / her example is without jQuery.

Comment: @Michael Giovanni Pumo: I noticed, hence the second "hack" solution :)

Comment: Second Hack Works Fine To me

Comment: @Michael Giovanni Pumo: When someone tags a `Javascript` question like this with `jQuery` too, I tend to assume they "may" want a jQuery alternative as that is a common request. I see you have removed that tag now from the question though.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Since the question has been answered and no jQuery was used, I felt it appropriate to remove the jQuery tag for future users.

Answer (score 2):

Your `click` action is being propagated to all parent elements of the `button`. To stop that, use `event.cancelBubble = true` (or, if you're using jQuery you can use `event.stopPropagation()`) in the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e.stopPropagation();`

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j81czwky/

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
    alert("Foo");
})

$("button").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert("Bar");
});


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td><button>Bar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```